# How to run a plain Java script file on crome browser's console

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-cognito

I am trying to follow along with the tutorial on the AWS Cognito with Reactjs.
I am new to both of these.

Link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qo5GFdN-Ck&list=PLaxxQQak6D_eARpHp6JdMq3rvD5A-WU9N&index=1

As you see at the end of the video the instructor runs the js file on the console.

I am trying to figure out how can I achieve this.

here is my js code.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { CognitoUserPool } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';

export default () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const poolData = {
    UserPoolId: 'us-east-1_xxxxxxxx',
    ClientId: '5g1uhpkbbm90oi352klxxxxxxx'
  };

  const UserPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolData);

  const onSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    UserPool.signUp(email, password, [], null, (err, data) => {
      if (err) console.error(err);
      console.log(data);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input
          value={email}
          onChange={event => setEmail(event.target.value)}
        />

        <input
          value={password}
          onChange={event => setPassword(event.target.value)}
        />

        <button type='submit'>Signup</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I tried to run it with "node App.js"
but it gave me this error

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I tried to add an HTML file in front of js and provide a script tag but it gave an error in the console.

```
Unexpected token '<'
```

I realized that the instructor didn't do any of these.

Could any help me with my dilemma?

Comment: You can't use `import` outside of a module, which I don't think you can use directly in the browser's console.

Comment: @evolutionxbox when you have a look that the tutorial that I am following, in that video he is running it

Comment: I don't think they run the code directly in the browser. Since React is being used it is _highly_ likely that they are using [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/).

Comment: You need some sort of compiler that change the code to something that you can use in the browser. For a basic react app you can use [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/)

Comment: @Reyno let me give this a try

Comment: The video doesn't show how they set up react.

Comment: @evolutionxbox exactly. Thank you for taking the time out. 
I was working on something else. I will try and get this sorted by following the link you shared

Comment: Have it running guys. Thank you so much. 
I also referred his repo it seems he used create-react-app method that you guys suggested.
You guys can add your answers accordingly